# relation between two columns Python

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I'm trying to work out how to determine a relationship between two columns in a dataframe. The relation is between Items and Total. I want to work out the sum Total amount for each 'Items' value, where Items are the number of items per basket and Total is the total amount/cost per basket. The columns:

```
    Date   Time    Basket   Items   Total
```

My current Python code to get each frequency of the number of items is:

```
items  = result['Items'].value_counts()
```

I've tried this code to get the totals (and others..):

```
Total_per_Items = result.groupby(['Items','Total'])
Totals = Total_per_Items['Total'].sum()
Totals
```

and get this output:

```
Items  Total 
1  0.00        0.00
   0.01        0.03
   0.02        0.02
   0.11        0.11
   0.22        0.22
   0.24        0.24
   0.28        0.28
   0.29        0.29
```

Where instead I want to get something like:

```
Items    Total
1        10500.65
2        2300.50
3        3450.34
```

I made up the output above but I'm sure you get the drift. It's got me baked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you the sum of `Total` by `Item`:

```
result.groupby(['Items'])['Total'].sum()
```

Example:

```
>>> result = pd.DataFrame({'Items': [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3],
                           'Total': [10, 20, 30, 20, 10, 20, 30]})
>>> result.groupby(['Items'])['Total'].sum()
Items
1    20
2    60
3    60
Name: Total, dtype: int64
```

This gives you a dataframe as result:

```
>>> result.groupby(['Items'])['Total'].sum().to_frame()

       Total
Items       
1         20
2         60
3         60
```

Comment: Ah, I was thinking I needed to group Total and Items instead of just items by itself..